# Error while compiling Activity life cycle

Tags: java

I am new to Java and learning Android App Development using Android Studio, I created Activity Life cycle and found the error mention below, please help me to solve this.
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edu.myfirstapplication/com.edu.myfirstapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)

Did some research and tried to edit the code but still the same issue.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView textView;
  EditText userName;
  EditText passWord;
  Button  loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void 
onClick(View view) {
                                                   Log.d("tag", "User Clicked on Login : User Name" +userName.getText().toString() + "Password"+passWord.getText().toString() );
                                               }


@Override
protected void onStart() { Log.d("tag", "On Start");
    MainActivity.super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d("tag", "On Resume"); MainActivity.super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() { Log.d("tag", "On Pause");
    MainActivity.super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d("tag", "On Stop"); MainActivity.super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() { Log.d("tag", "On Destroy");
    MainActivity.super.onDestroy();
```

> ```
> 08 17:32:09.036 10154-10154/com.edu.myfirstapplication
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.edu.myfirstapplication, PID: 10154
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edu.myfirstapplication/com.edu.myfirstapplication.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
> android.widget.Button
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
> android.widget.Button
>         at com.edu.myfirstapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
> 2019-08-08 17:32:09.067 10154-10165/com.edu.myfirstapplication
> I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 5619(1999KB)
> AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 51% free, 1429KB/2MB, paused
> 7.179ms total 30.387ms
> ```